# I want to be able to resample my time series data for the daily mean

Tags: python, date, time-series, date-formatting, date-math

I want to be able to resample my time series data for the daily mean. I have code for this, however the file I want to resample (an output file from a model) has time(d) where the days are numbered 1 to infinity rather than a date. Also, if rainfall occurred on a day, the output will have two values for that day with the second time(d) for that day having a fraction (eg. 1 and 1.00053). What I need is to convert these day-numbers into dates, starting at 01/01/1900. When there are two values for the same day (eg. 1 and 1.00053) - they need to have the same date as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe next time you can describe your question more clear with code you have already tried. Try this in Python.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-

import datetime

day = [1, 1.00053]

if __name__ == '__main__':


    day = map(round, day)

    srcDay = datetime.datetime.strptime('01/01/1990', '%d/%m/%Y')    
    result = []
    for i in day:
        delta = datetime.timedelta(days=i)
        result.append(srcDay+delta)

    # you can use any kind of format you like 
    print result[0].strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
```